# Difference between solaris & linux pagecache behaviour

Tags: linux, unix, memory-management, linux-kernel, solaris

I have observed following difference in behaviour of Linux & Solaris pagecache.

1.When we are doing buffered writes on solaris platform - Free memory is used by   pagecache(buffered writes) and if there is no memory demand from other applications, It consumes almost all of the free memory.

**Reproduction of above scenario**:
Os/platform : Solaris 11(5.11)
total physical memory : 116GB
Filesystem : ZFS.
**steps** :

```
-bash-4.4# mkfile 110g file //this will create 'file' filled with 0s size = 110g
```

If I check available free memory using 'top' it starts decreasing and reaches to almost few KBs.
From `echo "::memstat" | mdb -k` I saw, most of the memory is consumed by 'pagecache' column.

The above behaviour seems normal according to OS design. Because:
1) There was no memory demand from other applications at that time.
2) Subsequent reads to the files will be faster as data is present is pagecache.

If I spawn an application that demands memory (> than current free mem),  the request gets satisfied by stealing pages from pagecache (pages which are flushed to disk).

My question is - Why this behaviour is not observed on linux, I tried the above scenerio with Linux (other configs same). I did not see free memory getting consumed agrressively. 
How is Linux's pagecache different from that of Sol ?

Comment: Are you using ZFS on Linux? Linux may be creating a sparse file that takes 0 space.

Comment: No,  it is ZFS on solaris.

Comment: First, ZFS doesn't use the page cache, it uses it's own ARC - [Adaptive Replacement Cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_replacement_cache).  Along with @MaximEgorushkin 's comment about `mkfile` creating a sparse file on Linux, I suspect `top` is ignoring page cache usage on both Linux and Solaris and counting it as "free memory", but as ZFS doesn't use the page cache `top` isn't counting memory in the ZFS ARC as "free".  How long does creating that 110 GB file take?